# How to change an active call to hold state android programatically

Tags: android, call

I want to start a call programatically and change the state to hold after some time. Is it possible using package `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` ?

I can see  method like `toggleHold`  in `ITelephony.aidl` ( [Check this source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl) ). But how can i use this?

I tried by adding a ITelephony.aidl file  like

```
package com.android.internal.telephony; 

interface ITelephony {      

      boolean endCall();     

      void answerRingingCall();      

      void silenceRinger(); 

      void toggleHold();

}
```

And i tried to access the `toggleHold` methode like

```
ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
telephonyService.toggleHold();
```

Getting the error like

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.toggleHold`

Instead i can able end the call by calling  `telephonyService.endCall();`

How can io acheive to change the call state to hold?

**Note:**

I already see similar questions like [Android how to hold and unhold active phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846518/android-how-to-hold-and-unhold-active-phone-call) But not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

//unable to holdCall.so, I mute microhpne

```
public static void muteMicrophone(Context context) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);


    }
```